# What is the proper syntax for running a meteor generated node bundle using forever?

Tags: meteor

In the docs the procedure to run meteor on your own server is to run

```
meteor bundle bundle.tgz
```

Then extract this tarball..

```
tar -xzvf bundle.tgz
```

Then start a node server

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/<dbname> PORT=<server_port> ROOT_URL=http://sub.example.com/ node bundle/main.js
```

I'm trying to use forever to keep the node server up, but when I run the following command (specifics obscured), the forever process doesn't return and I have to CTRL+C to get back to the command line - very unforever like.

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/<dbname> PORT=<server_port> ROOT_URL=http://sub.example.com/ forever bundle/main.js
```

If I append an ampersand to run the process in the background then I get back to the command line and everything looks fine, but forever doesn't generate any logs or pid files and eventually the forever process dies.

Comment: you also need to use `start`

Comment: aw man... you're right, can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/<dbname> 
export PORT=<server_port> 
export ROOT_URL=http://sub.example.com/ 
forever start bundle/main.js
```

Comment: the start command was what I was missing, but this is also easier to read.

Answer (score 7):

This is my startup script, called from rc.local:

```
#/bin/sh
cd /home/nodeapp/
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeapp
export PORT=80
export ROOT_URL=http://$(hostname)/
export METEOR_SETTINGS=$(<settings.json)
forever start bundle/main.js
```

Hope it helps someone.

[]s

Auro

Comment: Can you explain or show some reference for the METEOR_SETTINGS variable? I'm trying to know how `$(<` works. Thanks.