# Run meteor.js in background

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I launch Meteor.js application in the background ?

I use next command:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/start_page meteor &
```

But application stops after some time when I disconnected from server. Is there any way to find out why my application stops ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is tied to the shell it was started in.  When the ssh connection closes the process stops.

Using [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) can solve this by keeping the remote terminal up after ssh session ends.

Others suggest using the node module 'forever'.  Some discussion on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529677/what-is-the-proper-syntax-for-running-a-meteor-generated-node-bundle-using-forev).

Comment: Thanks. I use symbol '&' on the command.  Is it not enough to untied the process from shell ?

Comment: I don't think that alone does it.  Lots more discussion [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session).

Answer (score 0):

Nope & at the end of the command is not enough. Typically to do this in a unix environment, u use nohup, which ties the process to the root user and not your current shell.